# How to determine days count on the current year using a certain date on ORACLE SQL dual table

Tags: sql, oracle

For example, date with YYYYMMDD as a format and considering the leap year as well

20160201 is the 32 day of the year

20160226 is the 57 day of the year

20161231 is the 366 day of the year

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `TO_CHAR` function, `'DDD'` gives you the day of year:

```
SELECT
    TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(DATE'2016-02-01', 'DDD')),
    TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DDD')),
    TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(DATE'2016-12-31', 'DDD'))
FROM
    dual
```

Comment: I just need the days count do you think by using 'SELECT TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(DATE'2016-02-26', 'DDD')) FROM dual' is enough to cater the days count even if this will be use for the next couple of years?